# Pycharm run slow when toggling breakpoint in Debug mode

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using Pycharm (version 2018.3) to develop my application.

When running the script in run mode or debug mode, the script runs in about **5 seconds.**

When toggling(enabling) breakpoint, it start to run very slowly(The script runs for like **3 minutes** instead of 5 seconds).

Any ideas why its happening?

Comment: Is it a plain or conditional breakpoint?

Comment: Just when clicking on a line of code that didnt have breakpoint before the run starts.

Comment: Is the code related somehow to app engine?

Comment: The code is a simulation. Just making computations over changing states. Its long so I dont add it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Pycharm 2018?

I had similar problem of slow run when moved to Pycharm 2018.
More people experienced it [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001715239-2018-3-very-slow).

After returning to Pycharm 2017, it was stable again.

Edit:
You can try 2019 now.

Comment: Do note that PÿCharm 2019 is also available for some time, so you may want to try that.